# crossfade background image in firefox with CSS not working

Tags: css, firefox, background, jquery-animate, transition

I know this has been brought up before but it was never resolved.

Does anyone know if you can crossfade a background image in firefox yet? I know you can do background image animations in chrome and explorer but it doesn't seem to work in FF yet. It works using colours but not images. I am not using jQuery

Here is my website:  http://www.moniquepompe.com

Here is my code, please help!:

```
body{ 
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;}
animation:myfirst 5s infinite;
-moz-animation: myfirst 5s infinite; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:myfirst 5s infinite; /* Opera */;
-webkit-background-size: cover;}


@keyframes myfirst
{0%   {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-   content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
25%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-   content/uploads/2013/02/background_2.png')}
75%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_3.png')}
100% {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
0%   {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
25%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_2.png')}
75%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_3.png')}
100% {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp- content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
25%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_2.png')}
75%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_3.png')}
100% {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
{
0%   {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
25%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp- content/uploads/2013/02/background_2.png')}
75%  {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_3.png')}
100% {background:url('http://moniquepompe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/background_1.png')}
}
```

Comment: I've come up with a temporary solution but it's not what I was hoping to achieve. It would still be nice to if there was a solution to my original problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use border property. image  takes so much time to load , so use border
see this
jsfiddle.net/EucZM/

Comment: I think maybe you answered the wrong question? My question has nothing to do with borders.

Comment: i Know you are asking for background image. it is not working in ff.SO I just suggest you please try border.

Comment: ok thanks Pawan. Borders don't work for me in this situation but thanks anyway.